# Don't raise OnPropertyChanged when deserializing

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

Let's say I have this class :

```
[XmlType]
public class TestModel : BindableBase
{
    private int _id;

    [XmlElement(Order = 7)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _id, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing a lot of serialization and deserialization (from/to Json with newtonsoft and from/to byte arrays with protobuf) and I would like to avoid calling the `SetProperty` method when setting the property during the deserialization.

Basically I would like to have something along the line with:

```
[XmlElement(Order = 7)]
public int Id
{
    get
    {
        return _id;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!serializing) 
            SetProperty(ref _id, value);
        else
            _id = value;
    }
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because first I don't need the event `OnPropertyChanged` to be raised during deserialization and secondly because it is costly in terms of performance.

I tried using the `OnDeserializing` and `OnDeserialized` to set a flag but while `OnDeserialized` lets me know when the deserialization is over, methods decorated with `OnDeserializing` are not called just before the deserialization but during the operation.

This code is in a Portable Class Library assembly so I cannot use `SerializationContext`.

Any clues/hints are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean methods marked with OnDeserializing are called just before the deserialization? Do you mean they're called after the object is instantiated but before the properties are set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing that comes into my mind is to use a parametrized constructor all over your code, which sets the "serializing" flag to false, and set the "serializing" flag to true in the parameterless constructor. Instead of the first one, you can use a Factory which will use the parameterless constructor also, but will set the flag appropriately after creation.

Comment: I cannot do that because the instances that have been deserialized are going to have their properties changed at runtime. It will be the same instance ; first it's going to be deserialized from byte arrays/json, then it's going to be manipulated outside of the assembly.

Comment: Yes, but this problem you've solved already - the OnDeserialized lets you know when the deserialization is over, doesn't it?

Comment: However this introduces a strange conceptual coupling - objects created by a default constructors are "special" and it's not very readable. And you can't make these constructors private because probably then you won't be able to deserialize them. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to mark such constructors with "[Obsolete]" attribute, to help guarding against using them explicitly in your code.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but I can't think of any other way of doing that for now.